# Creating a bootable usb that runs mainly off of ram, but saves files and applications to the same usb

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I am completely new to ubuntu, and I created a live usb with ubuntu 14.10. I booted up to the usb, but it was soo slow compared to using the test version of ubuntu. How can I get my live usb to run nearly as fast as the test version of ubuntu but still be able to install programs to the usb and save files without them getting deleted on restart?

A little bit of further background:
I have two usb's. A two gig sd card, and a 32 gig thumb drive. I booted to the (iso) test version of ubuntu on my two gig sd card and formatted the 32 gig thumb drive and installed ubuntu 14.10 to it. I shut down and removed my 2 gig (try ubuntu) sd card. I then booted my computer back up and ran the official copy of ubuntu off of my Usb Thumb drive, but since it was no longer running from ram, it was incredibly slow and lagged so bad. I would like to have this thumb drive as a portable Operating system that I can boot to multiple computers, but I cannot run at this slow rate. Is there a way to load more data to the ram so that it runs faster? Utimately, I would like to be able to run the majority of the OS in ram, but be able to install programs to the usb thumb drive, and save files (like cpp files) to the usb as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimize Ubuntu install on USB-drive for longer life](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59556/optimize-ubuntu-install-on-usb-drive-for-longer-life) and also of [Instruct Ubuntu to boot to RAM from flash drive using unetbootin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194501/instruct-ubuntu-to-boot-to-ram-from-flash-drive-using-unetbootin)

Answer (score 0):

You can split usb to two partition. One for booting ubuntu, second for data.
Simple mount second partition of usb and you data is available. This data is also available on any other pc or on the same pc when boot from hdd.

To speed up your live system try to add swap via file.
Create swap file and add them when running live.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/swap_file bs=1024 count=${size_of_additional_swap}
mkswap /path/to/swap_file
```

After booting a live sysyem turn on swap with

```
swapon /path/to/swap_file
```

Swap file can be on usb or on same partition like live distro.

Try, maybe this will be solution for you.

Comment: Linux swaps allow a system to harness more memory than was originally physically available. I read this about swaps. This looks like if I dont have enough ram, then I can store some of that memory on my hard drive. What im looking for is to utilize more ram. I have 16 gigs of ram, which should be plenty to run the OS, but it is hardly using any of it and is trying to run the whole OS off of the USB. How can I load more of the OS onto the ram to increase speeds?