# Is it possible to erase a LiveUSB while running off of it?

Tags: live-usb

I have a Ubuntu MATE bootable flash drive and want to try Ubuntu GNOME. However, the only computer that I have at the moment runs Neverware CloudReady which I can't use to erase the bootable drive and put Ubuntu GNOME on it. Is it possible to boot Ubuntu off the bootable drive and erase it?

Comment: It is only possible to erase the partition you're booting from if you unmount it. That is only possible if you boot with the `toram` kernel option (or something similar, not 100% sure any more) that loads all system parts into a RAM disk. This however requires enough RAM to hold all system data and still keep the OS running.

Comment: How dow you add that kernel option and is 4GB enough RAM to do it?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/194501/367990, and for basic actions (nothing resource hungry, probably you should even try to avoid web browsing) 4GB might be enough. Maybe. Try it.

Comment: So if I just run Gnome Disks and terminal I'll be fine?

Comment: Maybe. I can't promise you.

Comment: OK, but I don't need it anymore.